# Fragment as ViewGroup?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

When I go into the view hierarchy it show RelativeLayout as the Viewgroup for the TextView and AnalogClock. So where did the fragment view go? Isn't the fragment contain the RelativeLayout, TextView, and AnalogClock in fragment_main.xml since it is the one that is inflated in MainActivity.java? Also, where did the TextView with "TestTest" as its text go?

Here's my code:

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.micha.solo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**MainActivityFragment:**

```
package com.example.micha.solo;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.micha.solo.MainActivityFragment" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="TestTest" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</fragment>
```

**and fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <AnalogClock
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"` occupies the full height and width of the screen. you don't see the text